# Rename the Single .exe file name parameter using command line IsCmdBld.exe Installshield

Tags: command-line, command-line-arguments, installshield, installshield-2012

How do I specify the name for the executable using the command-line version of Installshield. I'm looking for the command line switch

I need to create a package based on the version I pass.

For ex : If I pass - 2.2.0,

```
SET RELEASE_VERSION="2.2.0"
ISCmdBld.exe -p "\Path\BuildProject.ism" -y %RELEASE_VERSION% -? MY_COOL_APP_%RELEASE_VERSION%.EXE
```

I need to know the switch (indicated as ? here) which will create **MY_COOL_APP_2.2.0.exe** after building and running the command line InstallShield build tool.

I tried using the values from the path variables at build time 
ISCmdBld.exe -p "\Path\BuildProject.ism" -y %RELEASE_VERSION% -l MYPathVar="MY_COOL_APP_%RELEASE_VERSION%"

I have associated the value of the path variable for the single .exe file in the Project-->Settings-->Application tab but still the build gives me the default setup.exe

Much appreciate your inputs

Comment: Any feature added now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no parameter for `IsCmdBld.exe` that directly changes the name of the resulting setup.exe file. For a couple predetermined names you could make multiple release configurations and select them (with `-r`, or product configurations via `-a`), but for your case that is unlikely to scale. Instead you should consider one of the following:

- Use automation (perhaps invoke a .vbs script) to edit the release configuration, and then build the project
- Build to a known name, and then rename the resulting file as the next step in your build script

Comment: Yeah. at the moment I'm renaming the setup.exe post build operation in my batch file as an alternative. But wanted to know if there a built-in approach inside Installshield itself

Comment: Any feature added now?